# getDrawingCache return null when run monkey

Tags: android, android-monkey

I have the follow code to get the screenshot

```
    View screen = getWindow().getDecorView();
    screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    screen.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    screen.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap bitmap = screen.getDrawingCache();
```

The code is in `onOptionsItemSelected` in UI thread.

It runs fine when I test it manually. However, when I run the app with monkey, `bitmap` is `null`I am not sure if it always null in monkey mode or just occasionally since monkey's randomness.

Any ideas that why monkey could behave differently? I do not want to blindly add a null pointer checker in later code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use buildDrawingCache(true) because buildDrawingCache() is same as buildDrawingCache(false).Make sure to copy bitmap to another one before using getDrawingCache() like below.

```
Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createBitmap(screen.getDrawingCache());
```

because its copy our bitmap before recycle() if you call setDrawingCacheEnabled(false).